# Accidentally deleted everything with GParted

Tags: partitioning, gparted, undelete

I wanted to format my USB stick in GParted and didn't see that my Computer drive was selected, so I ended up with this:

[image: Screenshot of disk]

I'm still logged in and everything is working right now.

So... Is this my last log in (& I can say farewell to the system) or is there a way to get things back?

(P.S.: I have a backup of important stuff.)

Comment: Is this your system disk or some other? I've never tried, but I suppose Ubuntu wouldn't let you to such a thing to system disk while it's working.

Comment: Have you actually done anything? You need to apply for the changes to take effect and you shouldn't even be able to modify mounted partitions.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the entire GParted window. That will clarify the situation.

Comment: Yes, this was a system disk. I unmounted and deleted (and applied) everything i could, only sda2 couldn't be deleted (that's actually the reason i realized that this isn't a usb drive :) Anyway, after an hour or so the system froze and after i restarted the system didn't load. Well i guess i tasted the linux medicine :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to recover lost partitions if no more actions have been done to the disk *(format, write...)*.

Boot from a Ubuntu LiveCD/USB on that machine, open a terminal and install `testdisk` with `sudo apt install testdisk`.

Then run `sudo testdisk` and follow the on screen *menu-like* instructions to try to recover with this tool.

If you still can't recover or want more options, check [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Lost_Partition) about data recovery from Ubuntu wiki.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help! In my particular case i figured it would probably be quicker to just do a new install and configure it back the way it was (because the system was quite new). But these are some valuable information, clearly written and i think this might come in handy in the future! :)

Comment: Glad to help. I also prefer starting from scratch and reinstalling _(in most cases)_, but like you said  one never knows when recovering is the _only_ way...